# How to populate a bidimensional array in the reverse way - C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, malloc

I'm trying to populate a bidimensional array in the reverse way but I'm getting always the same error: core dump.

When I say reverse way I mean, usually we do something like

```
for(int i=0; i<MaxColumns; i++)
   for(int b=0; i<MaxRows; b++)
      array[i][b] = random value;
```

What I'm trying to do is for each row, I want to populate that single row on every column and then pass to the next row and do the same. At this time I'm declaring dynamically a new row for each column.

This is what I was trying:

```
int i = atoi(argv[1]);
int **array = (int**)malloc(i * sizeof(int*)); 
for (lines =0; lines <MAXLINES; lines ++) { 
    for (colunms =0; colunms <i; colunms ++) {
        array[colunms] = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
        v=colunms+lines;
        array[colunms][lines]=v;
    }   
}
```

And the error goes on:

```
array[colunms][lines]=v;
```

------ LAST UPDATE TO PROBLEM ----

Already updated and although I tried this code

```
for (lines =0; lines <MAXLINES; lines ++) { 
    array[colunms] = (int*)malloc(colunms * sizeof(int));
    for (colunms =0; colunms <i; colunms ++) {
        v=colunms+lines;
        array[colunms][lines]=v;
    }
}
```

I keep getting core dumped on:

```
    array[colunms][lines]=v;
```

Comment: Well, where exactly have you declared variable `v`??? What is the type of this variable, and what kind of error are you getting (i.e., is it a compile-time error or a runtime error)?

Comment: didn't copy to the example but its declared as int. sorry.

Comment: "And the error goes on"... Is that the best you could do in describing this error???

Comment: the error on console is :   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
and the line that happened is where i try to populate

Comment: Maybe the compiler is objecting to your consistent misspelling of 'columns' as 'colunms'?   Actually, the compiler doesn't care as long as you're self-consistent, but it would be easier (less jarring) to read if the words was spelled correctly.

Comment: Im not using this words on my program, i just translated to English. But im sorry for misspelling it

Answer (score 1):

Thats simple enough. Instead of:

```
for(int i=0; i<MaxColumns; i++)
   for(int b=0; i<MaxRows; b++)
      array[i][b]=random value;
```

Use:

```
for(int b=0; i<MaxRows; b++)
   for(int i=0; i<MaxColumns; i++)
      array[i][b]=random value;
```

Your error though is in:

```
array[colunms] = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
```

You are allocating space for `1` element of `int` where you should be allocating for `colunms * sizeof(int)`. You should also do that outside the inner loop, like this:

```
int **array = (int**)malloc(MAXLINES * sizeof(int*)); 
for (lines =0; lines <MAXLINES; lines ++) { 
    array[lines] = (int*)malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    for (colunms =0; colunms <i; colunms ++) {
        v=colunms+lines;
        array[lines][colunms] = v;
    }   
}
```

Also, even though this code should work, it can be a problem in the future to assume this as `array[colunms][lines]` where it should be `array[lines][colunms]`.

Why? Because with `array[lines][colunms]` each `array[line]` represents a complete row with all its columns, which is a lot more practical for most cases.

In this form you will be able to declare functions to handle single records instead of handing it the entire "table".

Comment: Hey, the problem is that i can't simple do that when i need to "malloc" the columns and lines.. he gives core dumped because im probably trying to access space i didn't request for it .. and its strange.

Comment: @user3743144 I have updated my answer with the relevant details.

Comment: Hey again, that solution already tried and he kept getting core dumped, like i said the problem is when i try to put the value in the array , it seems that explode, im running on linux although

Comment: @user3743144 Yes, you are using confusing variable names that made it hard to realize what I was doing wrong. Usually variables like `i`, `j`, `k` are used for iterating the `for` loop instead of serving as sentinels. You made an inversion of the common practice. I have updated my code to something that should work.

Comment: I already tried to implement but it seems i get segmentation fault (core dumped) and to be honest i don't even understand how im getting this error.